# $\int_y^x \cos(e^t)\,dt=(\sin(e^t))]_y^x$

Tags: calculus

I have this problem: Originally, I had $F(x,y)=\int_y^x \cos(e^t)\,dt$. I want to find the partial derivate of x. So this is the solution given to me

$F_x(x,y)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_{t=y}^{t=x} \cos(e^t)\,dt=\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(e^t))]_y^x=\cos(e^x)$

I understand why $F_x(x,y)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_y^x \cos(e^t)\,dt$ and $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(e^t))]_y^x=\cos(e^x)$ but I can't see why $\int_y^x \cos(e^t)\,dt=(\sin(e^t))]_y^x$.

Comment: Hello,

Using the FTC, the answer should be 

$F'(x, y) = cos(e^x)$

Comment: The derivation of $sin(e^t)$ is $e^t cos(e^t)$ (chain rule)

Comment: So I know that $\cos(e^t)=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\sin(e^t)}{e^t}$. Do I use this?

Comment: I have problems to understand the top line. Do we have parameter integrals here (where x and y depend on t ) ?

Comment: Otherwise, there should be something wrong.

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: If we have parameter integrals, use the Leibniz formula.

Comment: @UsernameUnknown, there is something still wrong. What you have is called the cosine integral, it does not have an elementary antiderivative, hence you cannot use FTC on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middle steps are both wrong:
$$
F_x(x,y)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_{y}^{x} \cos(e^t)\,dt \neq \frac{d}{dx}(\sin(e^t))]_y^x \neq \cos(e^x)
.
$$
However,
$$
F_x(x,y)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_{y}^{x} \cos(e^t)\,dt = \cos(e^x)
$$
by *direct* appeal to the fundamental theorem of calculus (the variant which says that $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$, if $f$ is continuous).